How do I improve hybrid search on Weaviate?
I've been working on Hybrid Search using Weaviate. I use OpenAI's latest embeddings model, and then some other stuff. So, the problem is, for some queries, I would like to focus on specific properties while for others, I would like to focus on other properties more. I also have 2 axes on which I want to rank the recommendations - relevance and excellence.
Relevance would be how relevant they are to my search, and excellence would be how excellent the "document" is based on some score that I give it.
So far, the things I've tried are:

Cohere reranking. I saw that v3 reranking gave marginally better
results for short queries than the "Hybrid Score" for Weaviate
For shorter queries, I do more of a keyword search and for longer
queries, more of a semantic search (shifting the alpha value based
on word count)
Assigning weights for keyword search in Weaviate
Tried using a linear combination of my in house eval and relevancy
(reranked score/hybrid score) and sorted based on that. This didnt
really provide satisfactory results at all.

Are there any suggestions based on which I could try improving the Search results? I want:

To be able to "understand" what the query is for, and focus on that
property more in my vector DB schema for the search
For common queries, I want to be able to surface more "excellent"
recommendations, as if its common, rather than focusing on very very
relevant stuff, if it meets a certain level of relevancy and then is
really excellent, that is the best way to go and looks really good
in search results
For larger/more niche queries, focus on the relevancy a lot more
I think fine tuning Cohere's reranking model might be an option
here?
How do I factor in the excellence?

What are my options here, and where do I go from here? Also, I've been checking distributions of scores that are returned from Weaviate upon the hybrid search, and I see that in lot of cases, if, say, I return the top 800 people from my query, most of them (~500-700) fall in the range of <0.3 vector/keyword scores or they do not have keyword/vector scores at all in which case one score is just 0.
What are my options here?
